# Interpret JSON output using VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

We'd like to interpret the following JSON output and do something with it:

```
null
200
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    "Found Itzme",
    "Found Player232"
  ]
}
```

First we need to filter the output for the names, like:

```
Itzme
Player232
```

Finally we do something per each output line with the results, e.g.:

```
While read line 1 -
mytext.text = "Itzme"
While read line 2 - 
mytext.text = "Player232"
```

Comment: I hope u understand what I mean and can help me. Feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first import Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet library to your project and start experimenting with that library. Parsing JSON data using that is quite simple.

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try :)